# Effects of SSHing into a remote machine and logout

Tags: ubuntu

A silly question : I just logged out of a ssh session with a remote machine through cmd line. Is there anything that killed other jobs or turned the machine down? It all happened due to network connectivity and ssh session being hanged. I just had to ctrl + z at that point and it stated there are stopped jobs.

Remote machine : Ubuntu

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything could have stopped jobs or shutdown the machine. Check the logs. As for SSH shutting down the machine or stopping jobs, depends on the program you're using and if you set that program to shutdown the machine during disconnection. Highly unlikely that losing your connection from SSH did anything at all other than disconnect you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if network problems cause the connection to hang, it means data packets aren't going through. That of course means the client's "close connection" packets can't go through, either.

So during network problems, the server *doesn't know* that you've killed the client yet. It'll only figure this out if it tries to send more data and a) doesn't receive an acknowledgement, or b) receives a reset packet ("this connection no longer exists").

Either way, once it figures out that the SSH connection is broken, the sshd will send a "hangup" (SIGHUP) signal to whatever program was running in foreground (either your shell, or your text editor, or whatever). The shell will then send the same SIGHUP to all your background jobs, before exiting. Therefore your background jobs will also exit. (This is the reason tools like `nohup` exist, after all.)

If you kill `ssh` while the network is fine, the same happens – the server will receive a "connection reset" packet and send 'hangup' to the shell.

Finally, if you log out through the shell itself (using `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>), it'll also go through the same clean-up process by itself, although this time it has a chance to remind you about running jobs.

Comment: My network is back and I could ssh again to the machine, a clear indication, it was not shutdown. But I am not sure which background jobs were exited.